# Does apache have the equivalent to asp.net httpcontext.cache and output cache?

Tags: python, asp.net-mvc, apache

I am migration a site from asp.net-mvc and IIS onto apache.  Everything is migrated but there is one final piece where the asp.net-mvc site is using HttpContext.Cache and output cache attributes on some methods.

What is the equivalent on apache web server / python ([using this](http://www.modpython.org/))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [mod_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html) to see if it does what you have used HttpContext.Cache for.